# Which ExactTarget IP addresses to whitelist for AMPscript HTTP functions

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have some emails that use AMPScripts HTTPGet() function to retrieve data from a website that is not accessible unless whitelisted. We have an Enterprise 2.0 account on S7, and also a test account (located at mc.test.exacttarget.com).

After reviewing [this documentation](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/resources/exacttarget_ip_addresses_for_inclusion_on_whitelists/) I am still unsure exactly which IPs need to be whitelisted, specifically for AMPscript.

Comment: I see those 2 IPs are listed now in the document linked above. It's probably good practice to review and update your whitelist on a regular basis, to get any updates from the vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer, there are IPs used by S7 that are not listed on the documentation.

**S7:**
136.147.128.1-14  (the full range)

**Production Support:**
66.231.94.250

**Edit**: These addresses are now listed on the "IP Addresses for Inclusion on Whitelists" article referenced above.